# What motivates the concept of "pointers" in C, when the concept of numbers only would suffice?

Tags: c, pointers, int

Why do we use pointers in the C language to store addresses of variables? It would seem an unsigned int could simply be declared to store an address.

The difference between my question and those below are, they ask the reason for having different pointer types, while I asking the reason that the mere concept of a pointers exists within the language.

It's already clear that addresses are numbers referencing a memory location, so it's not clear why having access to only numbers was not sufficient.

Related but different questions:

- [Why do we have pointers other than void](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200404/why-do-we-have-pointers-other-than-)
- [Why data type is needed in pointer declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802585/why-data-type-is-needed-in-pointer-)

Comment: C have five unsigned in types, that can all be of different *or* the same size. Which unsigned integer type should we use, considering that none may be large enough to hold a memory address?

Comment: This question is a bit noobish and lacks a bit of research, but apart from that I actually think it is a really good question. It should be upvoted.

Comment: Furthermore, once you have the address in an unsigned integer variable, what would be the semantics to access the memory at that address? How would you be able to tell the difference between an integer holding an address, and an integer holding some other integer value that isn't an address?

Comment: I mean pointers just stores the addresses then why there is a need of a special data type if we can do that with an int

Comment: Because you can NOT do that with an int. On all 64bit platforms int is too small to hold a pointer. For that reason there is intptr_t for when you need to have an integer large enough to hold a pointer. For why we want to specify a pointer type instead of intptr_t see the duplicate question.

Comment: The duplicate is related, but in my opinion not really a duplicate of this question.

Comment: @JBL - Yeah, I was unsure myself. Then the OP commented *"I mean pointers just stores the addresses then why there is a need of a special data type if we can do that with an int"*

Comment: Most of the times (but not always) a pointer holds the address of some dynamically allocated memory zone. Read about [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation)

Comment: Why downvoating? It is an honest question!

Comment: Because pointer arithmetic relies on type - if `p` points to an object of type `T`, then `p+1` points to the *next object of that type*, not necessarily the next byte.  Pointers are *abstractions* of addresses with additional type semantics, and that's what makes them useful.  Also, pointer values don't have to be scalars - they may be aggregates like a page number and offset pair.

Comment: I do not agree of these duplicates. This is another question.

Comment: The two duplicate questions do give some very good reasons for why you would need a pointer type. Note that duplicates simply point to a useful answer that answers the question, it is irrelevant whether the questions themselves are identical or not.

Comment: @Cris this makes no sense to me is it documented in meta somewhere? "it is irrelevant whether the questions themselves are identical or not".   Regardless if it is I've voted to reopen because both the question and proper answers have subtle but significant differences.  This one is more about introducing the concept of a pointer into the language, the others are more about typing.  Yes there is overlap and common interest, but still distinct points to be made for each question.

Comment: @CrisLuengo True, but the answers does not fully answer the question either in this case.

Comment: @whitneyland: See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/376604) "Questions may be duplicates if they have the same (potential) answers."

Comment: @Cris thank you for the reference, however that says duplicates may have the same answers, which quite different from saying "it is irrelevant whether the questions themselves are identical or not".  I'm still not aware of any precedent for that being a well established principle on meta.  Best I can tell it may be relevant or it may not, with no way to generalize for all cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### TL;DR

It is completely possible to have a language without pointers. Actually, it is possible to write a C program where you store addresses in regular integer variables and then cast them to pointers. Calling pointers, and also the general concept of types, syntactic sugar is to stretch it a bit, but it's not completely untrue either.

### Long story

The reason is that it is very valuable to have different types. That allows the compiler to do type checking and automatic conversions. It also allows the compiler to warn you when you are doing something that probably is not what you intend. For instance, look at this C code:

```
int x;
int *p;
// Init x and p somehow
int y = p + x; // Legal, but you probably meant y = *p + x
```

An early language B, which predates C had only one type called "word". It was used for integers, pointers, floats or whatever. It was up to the program to interpret the bit pattern.

Consider this C code:

```
int i=5;
float f=3.5;
float x=f+i;
```

In the last statement, `i` will be promoted to `float` before a float addition is performed. This would not be possible without type information. Now `x` will have the value `8.5` (rounding errors ignored) but now consider this pseudocode that illustrates the problem you would have in a language like B:

```
word i, f, x;
i = 5;
f = 3.5;
x = i + f;
```

What do you expect the variable `x` to contain? And what type should that bit pattern represent?

When it comes to pointers, this is very valuable. Consider that you have two pointers, `char *cptr` and `int *iptr`. Now let's have a look at some pointer arithmetic. When adding an integer to a pointer we will offset the pointer *with respect to the size of the type*. So `*(cptr + 1)` will return the value that is one byte after `cptr`, while `*(iptr + 1)` will (typically) return the value that is on the address 4 or 8 bytes after `iptr`.

Here is an example that is very close to your question. Consider this C code:

```
float *p = malloc(10 * sizeof (*p));

for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    p[i]= i * 1.2;

for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    printf("%f\n", p[i]);
```

If we did not have pointer types, then we would have to write something like this instead:

```
unsigned p = malloc(10 * sizeof(float));

for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    *(p + i*sizeof(float)) = i * 1.2;

for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    printf("%f\n", (float) *(p + i*sizeof(float)));
```

If you REALLY want to, you can actually do stuff like this in C. Here is an example that compiles and runs, although with warnings and probably have undefined behavior, but it produced the expected result on my computer:

```
unsigned p = malloc(10 * sizeof(float));

for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    *((float*)p + i*sizeof(float)) = i * 1.2;

for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    printf("%f\n", *((float*)p + i*sizeof(float)));
```

Comment: i didn't knew about the "word" keyword. i really found your answer helpful

Comment: @MadhusudanBabar: If you're interested, there's a tutorial on the B programming language [here](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/btut.html).  You can see how it influenced the development of C.

Comment: @MadhusudanBabar `word` is not a keyword in B. Instead you would write `auto`. But given the context I thought that it would be clearer to write word. After all, I was not trying to write compilable B code, but only showing the benefits of a typed language.

Comment: Good answer here, just to note the answer is similar for all language features, even for why languages exists.  How/why do you design a language or language concept?  By thinking of abstractions of concepts that are unnecessary in principle, unnecessary technically, but as helpful as possible to humans to be more productive and efficient.  This human element is why language design requires more than than technical knowledge, it's subjective to some degree.  For example some people love this language, I find it to be a nightmare: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_(programming_language)#Examples

Comment: Last extreme example, if I recall correctly a single logic gate can be Turing complete.  For example imagine a single logic gate like this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_gate.  It does almost nothing right?  Yet you could write any application possible using only (lots and lots of) this simple low level component.  The question is would you be sane after doing so? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Because it helps *you*, the programmer, by providing a hint as to what that variable is for, what values it can have, and what operations you can do with it.

The computer doesn't care.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have mentioned, having a separate type for pointers clarifies intent and allows the compiler to perform checks related to using pointers.

Even without that, using an integer type for pointers makes sense **assuming** that memory is referenced as a flat array of bytes.  However, not all systems can necessarily represent a memory address with a single integer.

One notable example is an x86 processor in real mode.  When one of these processors starts up, it starts in real mode.  This mode goes all the way back to the original 16 bit 8086 processors.  Memory in this mode is addressed with a 16 bit segment and a 16 bit offset which together make up a 20 bit address.  They are combined by shifting the segment left by 4 bits and adding the offset.  For example:

```
segment: 0x1111
offset:   0x2222
address: 0x13332
```

In a layout such as this, it's also possible to have two pointers with different numerical values which reference the same address:

```
segment: 0x1110
offset:   0x2232
address: 0x13332
```

So one pointer with value 0x1111:0x2222 and another with value 0x1110:0x2232 point to the same address.

This addressing model also has the concept of near and far pointers, where a near pointer contains only the offset (and assumes the current segment in the CS register) while a far pointer contains both the segment and offset.

So you can't have just an integer to represent a pointer because it's not sufficient for some architectures.

Answer (score 0):

Because representing them differently is useful.  Would you also prefer to specify your strings by writing out the hex values of the characters?